# Godot- Issue with flip_h after enemy collides with the wall (2D)

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am using Godot 3.2 for a 2D project, and running a script for an enemy to change the direction (flip_h) when is colliding with the walls, however, when the enemy collides with the wall or another enemy the enemy change also the direction.

The code I am using is working only when collides for the first time (ONCE), after that isn't flipping the direction any more, any ideas?

thanks

```
extends "res://Actors/Actors.gd"

func _ready() -> void:
    set_physics_process(false)
    _velocity.x = -speed.x
    $enemy1.flip_h = true

func _physics_process(delta) -> void:
   _velocity.y += gravity * delta
   $enemy1.play("walk")

   if is_on_wall():
    _velocity.x *= -1.0
    $enemy1.flip_h = false

_velocity.y = move_and_slide(_velocity, FLOOR_NORMAL).y
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone pointed to my answer to use :

`$enemy1.flip_h = !$enemy1.flip_h`

because I was calling the "false" all the time.

However, he gives me another solution to be out of:

`is_on_wall()`

and suggested:

```
if _velocity.x > 0:
   $enemy1.flip_h = false
elif _velocity.x < 0:
   $enemy1.flip_h = true
```